# Como recuperar dados de uma consulta feita com objeto "ADODB.Command"?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, delphi

Com base no código abaixo, onde posso recuperar os resultados do `ADODB.Command`?

Esta unit sempre trabalhará com *stored procedure*, e os tipos de parâmetros que serão usados são do tipo `input` e `output`.

```
unit uadolibrary;

interface

uses
  ComObj, Variants;

function ADOStart(strConexao: AnsiString): Boolean;
function ADOStop: Boolean;
function ADOConfigParams(ParamName: string; ParamType, ParamIO,
  ParamSize: integer; Val: variant; CanClear: Boolean = False): Boolean;
function ADOSetParamVal(ParamName: string; val: variant): Boolean;
function ADOGetParamVal(ParamName: string): Variant;
function ADOGetValue(_Indece: integer): Variant;
function ADOExecute(procname: string): Boolean;

const
  {Param Data Types}
  adInteger = 3;
  adSingle = 4;
  adDate = 7;
  adBoolean = 11;
  //adTinyInt = 16;
  adVarBites = 16;
  adUnsignedTinyInt = 17;
  adDateTime = 135;
  advarChar = 200;

  {Param Directions}
  adParamInput = 1;
  adParamOutput = 2;
  adParamReturnValue = 4;

  {Command Types}
  adCmdText = 1;
  adCmdTable = 2;
  adCmdStoredProc = 4;
  adCmdTableDirect = 512;
  adCmdFile = 256;  

implementation

var
  ADODBConnection,
  ADORecordSet,
  ADOCommand: Variant;

function ADOStart(strConexao: AnsiString): Boolean;
begin
  try
    ADODBConnection:= CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
    ADODBConnection.ConnectionString:= strConexao;
    ADODBConnection.Open;
    ADORecordSet:= CreateOLEObject('ADODB.Recordset');
    ADOCommand:= CreateOLEObject('ADODB.Command');
    ADOCommand.ActiveConnection:= ADODBConnection;
    ADOCommand.CommandText:= 'Procedure';
    ADOCommand.CommandType:= adCmdStoredProc;
    Result:= True;
  except
    begin
      if not (VarIsEmpty(ADODBConnection)) then
      begin
        ADODBConnection.Close;
        ADODBConnection:= Unassigned;
      end;
      if not (VarIsEmpty(ADOCommand)) then
        ADOCommand:= Unassigned;
      if not (VarIsEmpty(ADORecordSet)) then
        ADORecordSet:= Unassigned;
      Result:= False;
    end;
  end;
end;

function ADOStop: Boolean;
begin
  try
    if not (VarIsEmpty(ADODBConnection)) then
      ADODBConnection.Close;
    ADODBConnection:= Unassigned;
    ADORecordSet:= Unassigned;
    ADOCommand:= Unassigned;
    Result:= True;
  except
    Result:= False;
  end;
end;

function ADOConfigParams(ParamName: string; ParamType, ParamIO,
  ParamSize: integer; Val: variant; CanClear: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  _W: integer;
  DerivedParamSize: integer;
begin
  try
    case ParamType of
      adInteger: DerivedParamSize:= 4;
      adSingle : DerivedParamSize:= 4;
      adDate   : DerivedParamSize:= 8;
      adBoolean: DerivedParamSize:= 1;
      adVarBites: DerivedParamSize:= 1;
      adUnsignedTinyInt: DerivedParamSize:= 1;
      adDateTime: DerivedParamSize:= 8;
      advarChar: DerivedParamSize:= ParamSize;
    end;

    if CanClear then
      for _W:= 0 to (ADOCommand.parameters.count) - 1 do
        ADOCommand.parameters.delete(0);

    ADOCommand.parameters.append(
      ADOCommand.createparameter(ParamName, ParamType, ParamIO,
        DerivedParamSize, Val));
    Result:= True;
  except
    Result:= False;
  end;
end;

function ADOSetParamVal(ParamName: string; val: variant): Boolean;
begin
  try
    ADOCommand.Parameters[ParamName].Value := val;
    Result:= True;
  except
    Result:= False;
  end;
end;

function ADOGetParamVal(ParamName: string): Variant;
begin
  try
    Result:= ADOCommand.Parameters[ParamName].Value;
  except
    Result:= varEmpty;
  end;
end;

function ADOExecute(procname: string): Boolean;
begin
  try
    ADOCommand.CommandText:= procname;
    ADOCommand.CommandType:= adCmdStoredProc;
    ADORecordSet:= ADOCommand.Execute;
    Result:= True;
  except
    Result:= False;
  end;
end;

function ADOGetValue(_Indece: integer): Variant;
begin
  Result:= ADORecordSet.Fields.Item[_Indece].Value;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Consegui resolver, o problema esta na minha stored procedure.
aqui eu recupero os dados retornados:

function ADOGetParamVal(ParamName: string): Variant;
begin
  try
    Result:= ADOCommand.Parameters[ParamName].Value;
  except
    Result:= varEmpty;
  end;
end;

Comment: você pode postar a resposta para sua pergunte a desta forma a pergunta deixa de parecer sem resposta na lista e, caso alguem tiver um problema parecido pode encontrar a resposta o/! #FicaDica. Bem vindo ao [pt.so]

Answer (score 3):

Conforme [citado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48130/como-recuperar-dados-de-uma-consulta-feita-com-objeto-adodb-command#comment97275_48130) pelo usuário @AndersondeOliveira, é no código abaixo que são recuperados os dados retornados:

```
function ADOGetParamVal(ParamName: string): Variant;
begin
  try
    Result:= ADOCommand.Parameters[ParamName].Value;
  except
    Result:= varEmpty;
  end;
end;
```